# Has Mountain Lion helped take advantage of multiple displays?

Tags: macos

after using Lion I was frustrated by the lack of multiple display integration it had. When I swiped between spaces, the secondary display served no purpose but to display that gray linen pattern that we're starting to see appear everywhere.

Has anyone discovered a feature in Mountain Lion that allows more function to come out of a secondary display? I would really hope there is.

Thanks for the help,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

The only change in Mountain Lion related to multiple displays is the ability to make an app go full-screen on a display other than the main one. Unfortunately, you can still only have one full-screen app open at once (the linen covers whatever display the app isn't on).

I recommend using a window manager like [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) to easily make apps take up the full screen space and switch them between displays quickly.